# Accessing data in Google Cloud Storage without downloading it

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-filestore, google-cloud-ai

Is there a way by which I can expose data in google cloud storage to a VM without completely downloading it all at once on the VM.

Amazon Sagemaker [Fast File Mode (FFM)](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/10/amazon-sagemaker-fast-file-mode/) exposes the data in S3 to machine learning application in such a way that it appears as if it is accessing a local file system. This provides the convenience of accessing the data as if it was stored locally without the overhead and cost of actually downloading it before training.

Is something similar also available in GCP? Can GCP's [Filestore](https://cloud.google.com/filestore) be used for this purpose?

Comment: Try GCSFuse. https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/improve-workflow-with-cloud-storage-fuse-89b8d76d0886

Comment: Is "Reading" data different of "Downloading" data?

Comment: By reading I meant streaming the data - this would allow model training to start without waiting for the complete dataset to be downloaded first. This is what Amazon Sagemaker's Fast File Mode (FFM) provides. Is there something similar in GCP?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage is an object storage API. As a result, it isn't really designed to be "mounted" within a VM. It is designed to be highly durable and scalable to extraordinarily large objects.

However, as mentioned by @Ricco D you can use [gcsfuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) to mount it as a filesystem, that method has pretty significant drawbacks. For example, it can be expensive in operation count to do [even simple operations](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse#cost_breakdown_example) for a normal filesystem.

Comment: Is there something similar to Amazon Sagemaker's Fast File Mode (FFM) in GCP?